# Is it still possible to get Facebook friends email list?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ecmascript-6, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi please help I'm running the code below to fetch user's details like name and email, but is it also possible to get their FB friends email? maybe change this

> FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}*

into this

> FB.api('/me/**friends**', {fields: 'name,email'} **?**

and display it as an array like this in the console?

```
[{email: 'someone0@email.com'},
{email: 'someone1@email.com'},
{email: 'someone2@email.com'},
{email: 'someone3@email.com'}]
```

You can test the sample page from here: https://domain/referral

```js
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Set YOUR APP ID
          // channelUrl : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
        {
         if (response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
            //SUCCESS
    
        }    
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";
    
            //FAILED
        } else 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";
    
            //UNKNOWN ERROR
        }
        }); 
    
        };
    
        function Login()
        {
    
            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) 
               {
                    getUserInfo();
                } else 
                {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
             },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos,user_friends'});
    
        }
    
    
      function getUserInfo() {
            FB.api('/me',{fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
    
          var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
              str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
              str +="<input type='button' value='Get Friends' onclick='getFriends();'/>";
               str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
              str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;
    
        });
        }
    
    function getFriends() {
        FB.api('/me/friends',{fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
            if(response.data) {
                $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                    console.log(friend.name + ' has email:' + friend.email);
                });
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    }
    function getPhoto(){
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
    
          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;
    
      });
    }
    
    function Logout() {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }
    
      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>
    
    <div align="center">
      <h2>Facebook OAuth</h2>
      <div id="status">
      <img src="http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/LoginWithFacebook.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="Login()"/>
      </div>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      <div id="message">
      Logs:<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `maybe change this ... into this` ... did you try?

Comment: I did tried, its inside this function getFriends(), there's isn't anything displaying in the console.

http://prntscr.com/gcsbpy
getUserInfo() is working though

Comment: did you try some simple debugging ... what is `response` in that callback?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gcsf6j nothing, it returns undefined

Comment: really? did I say `what is response.email` ? I'm sure I said `what is response` - forgive me if my question was at all unclear

Comment: Hi okay this is the response i get: http://prntscr.com/gcshhu

Comment: so, the simple answer is `/me/friends` doesn't do what you want :p

Comment: A user’s email is only accessible after they personally grant your app permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check this ?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

If i do what you do in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

That the response facebook give

> #### Query
>
> `curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/friends?access_token=<accesstoken sanitized>"`
>
> #### Response
>
> `{
>       "data": [],
>       "summary": {
>         "total_count": 8
>       },
>       "__debug__": {
>         "messages": [
>           {
>             "link": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0",
>             "message": "Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total
>   number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.",
>             "type": "info"
>           }
>         ]
>       }   }`
>
> #### Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
>
> - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.10

Has you can see

> Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. > total_count in summary represents the total
>    number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app

So you can't get you friends like this.
And like [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) say

> A user’s email is only accessible after they personally grant your app permission.